# How to create an array of array or vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

How to create a vectors out of three vector <string> ?

Here is my desired structure:

```
results = [
  [vector1[0],vector2[0], vector3[0]],
  [vector1[1],vector2[1], vector3[1]],
  [vector1[2],vector2[2], vector3[2]]
]
```

This is how I initialize my variables:

```
vector< string> vector1;
vector< string> vector2;
vector< string> vector3;

vector< vector< string> > results;
```

Comment: Replace the two outer layers of `[]` with `{}` and you're done.

Comment: How do i create this using a for loop?

Comment: If your 3x3 dimensions are fixed, consider using `std::array<std::array<std::string,3>,3>` as it's a lot more space and time efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach for example can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
    std::vector<std::string> v2 = { "11", "22", "33" };
    std::vector<std::string> v3 = { "111", "222", "333" };
    
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v;
    
    auto n = std::min( { v1.size(), v2.size(), v3.size() } );
    
    v.reserve( n );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( { v1[i], v2[i], v3[i] } ); 
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : item )
        {
            std::cout << s << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 11 111 
2 22 222 
3 33 333
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a multi-dimensional array with for loops if I read your comment to Quentin right.

Honestly, I'm trying to find something I can answer so I can post my first question on stackoverflow, so I'm looking for anything I can help answer.

This is an example of a 2 dimensional array.

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    // an array with 3 rows and 2 columns.

    int x[3][2] = { {0,1},
                    {2,3},
                    {4,5} };

    //This shows the position on the elements in the array
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < 2; columns++)
        {
            cout << "Element at x[" << rows
                << "][" << columns << "]: ";
            cout << x[rows][columns] << endl;
        }
    }

    //This will output the array
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < 2; columns++)
        {
            cout << x[rows][columns];
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WruLA.png)